# config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'

Tags: software-installation, compiling, install-from-source, makefile

I'm trying to install mod_WSGI on Ubuntu 12.04. Here is the set of commands that I'm following:

```
wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
tar xvfz mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-3.4
./configure
make
make install
echo "LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
a2enmod wsgi
a2dissite default
```

However, when I do ./configure, it gives me this output:

```
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 1747: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1747: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1748: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1751: /: Is a directory

checking for python... /usr/bin/python
./configure: line 1920: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'
```

I'm following this tutorial in case you are curious: http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/

Answer (score 1):

I believe `apxs` is included in [apache2-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apache2-dev) [image: Install apache2-dev]. I suggest you do:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

After it and its dependencies are installed, try `configure` again. I got:

```
chili@T410:~/mod_wsgi-3.4$ ./configure
checking for apxs2... /usr/bin/apxs2 
checking Apache version... 2.X 
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```